# Filter entity with class of expressions

Tags: c#

I created Person entity

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Fullname {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

So next i want to filter it. So i also did readmodel for Person.

```
public class PersonReadModel
{
    public Expression<Func<int, bool>> Id {get;set;}
    public Expression<Func<string, bool>> Fullname {get;set;}
    public Expression<Func<int, bool>> Age {get;set;}
}
```

And here implementation

```
var filter = new PersonReadModel
                  {
                    Id = (id) => id > 100,
                    Age = (age) => age > 20
                  }
```

As you see i want to filter persons who are older than 20 and have id bigger than 100.

And question is how to apply filter variable to where clause

```
_personRepository.GetAll().Where(? filter variable ?)
```

Is it able to do?
I hope my explanation is understandly, if not i'm sorry.

Comment: It is *possible* to combine expressions at the tree level, but it is *really quite hard* - frankly, I'd just use `Where(yourIdFilter).Where(yourAgeFilter)` - I don't quite understand what `PersonReadModel` is doing here, though... or how that relates to `Person`. What you really need are filters like `Expression<Func<Person, bool>>` with examples like `p => p.Id > 100`. Can you clarify the role of `PersonReadModel` here?

Comment: @MarcGravell It offers every property from entity to filter. But I see it will be very hard to do as i would like. But i like your proposition to use "Where(yourIdFilter).Where(yourAgeFilter)". But still don't know how to put filter.Id to where clause. Maybe _personRepository.GetAll().Where(person => filter.Id.Invoke(person.Id) ?).Where(person => filter.Age.Invoke(person.Age) ?)

Comment: @syyl did you perhaps mean something like: `public Expression<Func<Person, bool>> ById(int id) => p => p.Id > id;` ? the expressions you've posted don't really make sense - it needs to be a predicate that filters `Person` instances

Comment: @MarcGravell That's what i talking about.

Comment: @MarcGravell `public Expression<Func<Person, bool>> ById(Func<int, bool> id) => p => id.Invoke(p.Id);` `list.Where(filter.ById(id => id == 1 || id == 2).Compile())` Yeah it is either good idea. Thank you. My last question is whether it will work with entity at SQL(IQueryable) or at compiling program (Enumerable)

Answer (score 1):

From your condition, You can use `Where` like this directly

```
var filter = _personRepository.GetAll().Where(x=>x.Id > 100 && x.Age>20);
```